# Core Data causing exception when running in share extension

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, ios-extensions, ios8-share-extension

I'm building a share extension for my app, which has meant initialising the Core Data database from the shared directory:

```
let directory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: applicationGroupIdentifier)!
let storeURL = directory.appendingPathComponent("database")
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStore(at: storeURL)
```

Running the regular app, this all works as expected. But then running the Share Extension, it hits an exception at the first fetch request:

```
return DataUser.mr_findAll(with: predicate, in: context) as! [DataUser]
```

Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this - as I mentioned, it's running the same code as the regular app at the point it hits the exception.

Comment: Are you sure that your data model and your `DataUser` class are both included in the share extension target?